# Different colors for hovering over buttons in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-mobile-navbar

So as the title says, I'm trying to have my Navbar using Twitter Bootstrap to have different colors when hovering over particular buttons. Here is my index.html code snippet:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frank does...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

The goal is to have the different buttons on the navbar (page 1, page 2, etc.,) be different colors. However, I don't know how to do that. I tried placing `<Div>` on the `li` elements such as:

`<div class="home"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></div>`

but that somehow messes up the structure of the navbar, messing up the navbar and making the home button go above the navbar.

How can I make it so that each `li` element can have its own `hover` color?

Also, here is my CSS code that changes the hover color to red, but only red.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse li a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse li a:focus{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pseudo Classes for this: See [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frank does...</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```